# Casting with AVX intrinsics

Tags: c++11, avx, avx2

There are two ways of casting with AVX2, either:

```
__m256i b = ...set register...
auto c = (__m256d)b; // version 1
auto d = _mm256_castsi256_pd(b); // version 2
```

I assume that both of these should give same results. The [official manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&text=cast&expand=3921,595,612) from Intel says that there is zero runtime latency for version 2. Can I use version 1 as well with a zero latency assumption? In addition can I assume casting from any to any register type with version 1 is zero latency.

Comment: If you're interested in portability then it's probably best to use version 2 - the most troublesome compiler is MSVC, which I think will complain about version 1. (It's been a while since I had to address this though, so you might want to check for yourself with whatever compiler(s) you intend to support).

Comment: Thanks - Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Additionally, I did try out version 1 and it does seem to have some overhead in my experiment. Nonetheless it would be better to have a more technical and complete answer.

Comment: What experiment did you do to try version 1?  I think any compiler that accepts it will treat it as a reinterpret cast like version 2, but missed-optimization is always a possibility.  More likely though your experiment was flawed.  Did you check the asm output of the compiler?  (Anyway, good question.  I think the answer is that version 2 is always recommended for portability, but there's no reason to expect either version to assemble to any extra instructions to munge the bits at all.)

Comment: Attempting to write a templated horizontal register merge(also called `BitonicMerge` in the literature) for SIMD sorting a million elements in AVX2. The idea was that since shuffles on `ps` and `epi32` would work in a similar way - I could make it templated by careful typecasting like in version 1. Will check the ASM output like you advised and revert soon.

Comment: That sounds overcomplicated.  More likely you introduced extra bypass-delay latency on whatever CPU you're using by using FP shuffles or blends between integer compares, or vice versa.  (Intel SnB-family CPUs normally don't have domain-crossing penalties for shuffles, but they do for blends.  http://agner.org/optimize).  Or the different shuffles you used optimized differently or have different throughputs!  Definitely sounds like the difference you measured wasn't due to the cast itself, unless the compiler has a missed optimization for casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in gcc, 'version 1' is exactly how 'version 2' is implemented:

```
extern __inline __m256d __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm256_castsi256_pd (__m256i __A)
{
  return (__m256d) __A;
}
```

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_1_0-release/gcc/config/i386/avxintrin.h#L1440

Clang is essentially the same:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_60/lib/Headers/avxintrin.h#L4449

I did not look for other compilers, but I don't assume any magic happens there either.

Still, for portability and readability I would suggest using `_mm256_castsi256_pd`, or if that is too much writing, encapsulate this into your own (inlined) function. C-Style casts are relatively hard to find in source code, should you ever need to refactor them.